# Use jQuery to create edit in place div and have new div available for edit just beneath it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, edit-in-place

I'm new to [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) and would like to know if it is possible to create and edit-in-place div that I can click on, type some text, have it save and immediately have another div dynamically pop up beneath it that will allow the same capability to type in and save, so on and so forth. If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.edit_area').editable(function(value, settings) {
            return (value);
        }, {
            type: 'textarea',
            onblur: 'submit',
            indicator: 'Saving...',
            callback: function(value, settings) {
                var thisData = $(value);

                $.post('<%=Url.Action("SetPostieNotes", "Posties") %>',
                'postieNotes=' + escape(thisData)
                );
                var divTag = document.createElement("div");
                divTag.id = "div";
                divTag.setAttribute("align", "center");
                divTag.className = "edit_area";
                divTag.innerHTML = "Test Dynamic Div.";
                document.body.appendChild(divTag);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) for the edit-in-place functionality, and use it's callback functions to spawn the new div below the existing one.

---

You're not really using all that jEditable has to offer, try something like this (I am unable to test this right now but it should give you some ideas):

```
$(function() {
    $('.edit_area').editable('<%=Url.Action("SetPostieNotes", "Posties") %>', {
        callback: function(v, settings) {
            var new_div = $('<div />')
                          .addClass('edit_area')
                          .editable('<%=Url.Action("SetPostieNotes", "Posties") %>', settings);

            $(this).after(new_div);
        }
    });
});
```

That should be all there is to it. You don't need to do the submitting yourself, that's what jEditable is for. Just supply the URL you wish to save to as the first parameter, and settings as the second.

Comment: would you happen to have a code example? please see what I have above.

Answer (score 0):

I actually started by using jEditable and moved on to tectual's editables() plugin instead
Here is the code i'm using https://github.com/relipse/jQuery-Editable/blob/master/jquery.editable.js